# Security issues with online-judge

Tags: c++, c, linux, operating-system

I am involved in making an online-programming-judge supporting C/C++ like SPOJ,UVA etc on Linux machine(Ubuntu). The code itself is in C++ . I have to prevent the server from malicious code.
I plan to implement security in 2 steps.
1. By jailing (sandboxing) the executing code with chroot system call in a folder with restricted environment. I came across a utility [Jailkit](http://olivier.sessink.nl/jailkit/), but i think the system call alone will suffice my work as i don't have to jail the users, only the executing code. For creating a run time environment in folder i copied the following files along with files for creating a restricted shell (only shell builtin are allowed)

`$ ldd ./a.out

linux-gate.so.1 =>  (0x00f4c000)
libstdc++.so.6 => /usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6 (0x007a5000)

libm.so.6 => /lib/tls/i686/cmov/libm.so.6 (0x00b80000)

libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x00e0c000)

libc.so.6 => /lib/tls/i686/cmov/libc.so.6 (0x00110000)

/lib/ld-linux.so.2 (0x00f7c000)`

where a.out is an executable c++ file.

**Problems encountered:**
i)I have tried few programs which are running fine in jail. But can anybody confirm that these file will be sufficient for all algorithm-intensive codes i.e no need to handle any system call explicitly.
ii) It will be great if anybody can suggest any method to restrict some system calls by restricting runtime libraries supplied to jail folder as fork(),socket() etc which are not expected by a code.
iii) Just for sake of knowing, i have also copied the file shown by `ldd /usr/bin/gcc` and /usr/bin/gcc. But i am unable to use gcc in jail with error
`bash-4.1# /usr/bin/gcc try.c 
gcc: error trying to exec 'cc1': execvp: No such file or directory`
How can i fix it?

2.By tracing the system calls with the help of [ptrace](http://www.linuxjournal.com/article/6100) and KILLing the running code if it uses some suspicious system calls. Now problem is of what system calls should be banned ? What i feel is restricting **fork(), vfork(), and execve()** will do the work because there is a time limit( hardly > 10 sec) for each program to execute. After that it will be automatically killed and there is no other way to create another process except fork(), vfork(). But since my thoughts are bounded by my imagination, it will be great if anybody got other opinions to bend the things here.

---

So basically i am worried about i) and ii) point in "problems encountered" and if somebody can think of a way to hack after restrictions pointed in 2nd point.

Comment: So what's the security issue or the question here?

Comment: @AJG85: I have already mentioned the my problems. Definitely i am looking for their solutions.

Comment: Can the down-voter explain the reason..?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The single biggest security risk of running something like this is the possibility of making outgoing network connections on port 25. Someone will find your service, make thousands of dollars spamming, and you'll get banned by your host. Plus you'll make everyone else on your hosting provider/isp hate you for getting the whole ip block blacklisted in every overzealous anti-spam baron's databases.

Fortunately `iptables` can block locally originating packets based on the uid of the process that created them. This is probably the least obtrusive way to protect yourself against becoming an aid to spammers, but you might just use a more restrictive firewall if the box doesn't need to make legitimate outgoing connections.

Also note that, these days, outgoing http and https connections might be just as useful for spamming (message boards, compromised Twitter and FB accounts, etc.) as smtp, so you might really want to do some heavier blocking or just block network access entirely.

Comment: Thanks for suggesting the use of iptables for extra precaution, though I have taken care of this issue by setting a timeout limit for the running code and not allowing it to make any other process.

Comment: Timeout limits do not take care of the issue. Opening a socket and sending spam takes virtually zero time. You really need to block network access.

Answer (score 4):

you may want to look at this project: an online-judge oriented sandbox library. http://sourceforge.net/projects/libsandbox/

Answer (score 1):

Why do you want to invoke the compiler in jail? It does may calling external programs like `cc1`. Invoking the checked program only is ok. You can review the [patch](http://www.ejudge.ru/download/linux-2.6.26.3-2.6.26.3-cher1.diff) that serves the same purpose as you specify.

Computation-intensive code can do a lot before you program detects using `fork()` and bans it, for example, create a fork bomb.

Comment: i am not invoking compiler in jail. That was only to know in case i have to. I metioned "for the sake of knowing" in my question.Just trying to figure out the general method for dumping any program in jail. And won't ptrace will block the child whenever it enters the system call? man page suggest PTRACE_SYSCALL Restarts  the stopped child as for PTRACE_CONT, but arranges for   the child to be stopped at the next entry to or exit from a system  call,  or  after execution of a single instruction.

Comment: debugging will have impact when a lot of system calls are used. Eg. when there are multi-megabyte tests and they are reading byte-by-byte with `read` syscall. If fread is used, there will be buffer in libc, so 1 syscall per 4096 bytes.