# How to prevent system calls in online judge?

Tags: sandbox

I want to protect other folder on the server from the system call in the program.How can it be done?

I have tried chroot but i am having problem implementing it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Security issues with online-judge](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5328075/security-issues-with-online-judge)

Answer (score 1):

Try [EasySandbox](https://github.com/daveho/EasySandbox).
It uses seccomp (a sandboxing mechanism in Linux kernel) for sandboxing C/C++ codes.